# Is there any function in the standard library to return the larger or smaller of two numbers?

Tags: math, rust

I can implement this myself with the following code:

```
fn max(a: f32, b: f32) -> f32 {
    if a > b {
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}
```

Implementing it myself feels redundant.

Comment: Your function body would normally be written `if a > b { a } else { b }`, one line.

Comment: Your function does not account for `NaN` and all the other "strange" floating point values. Please read [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: What result would you want if `a` was NaN?  If `b` was NaN?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are such functions

- [`std::cmp::min`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/fn.min.html)
- [`std::cmp::max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/fn.max.html)

As of Rust 1.21, there are also methods provided by `Ord`:

- [`Ord::min`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#method.min)
- [`Ord::max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#method.max)

[None of these work for floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394546/get-the-minimum-of-two-floating-point-values). For that use

- [`f64::min`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.min)
- [`f64::max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.max)

(or the `f32` equivalent)